# For CNOT gate with control qubit set to 1, the measured state of the second qubit unexpectedly depends on the measurement

Tags: quantum-state, programming, qiskit, measurement, simulation

I have the following circuit in qiskit. It is a simple CNOT operation with the control qubit set to 1, by running the control qubit through an X-gate.

However, when I measure the 2nd qubit, I get the state $|00\rangle$,  not $|11\rangle$.

If I add a measurement of the control qubit, I do see $|11\rangle$ as the final result.

I fully expected $|11\rangle$ as the outcome regardless of whether I measure a single or both qubits

```
from qiskit import ClassicalRegister, QuantumRegister, QuantumCircuit
from qiskit import execute
from qiskit import BasicAer
from math import *
q0 = QuantumRegister(2, "q0") # one ancilla qubit
c0 = ClassicalRegister(2, "c0") # n classical bits for output
qc = QuantumCircuit(q0,c0)
qc.x(q0[0])
qc.cx(q0[0], q0[1])
  #qc.measure(q0[0],c0[0]) <= when commented out I measure |00>
qc.measure(q0[1],c0[1])
qc.draw()
 job = execute(qc,backend=BasicAer.get_backend('qasm_simulator'))
 job.result().get_counts()
```

[image]

Comment: This is not an answer (but I'm not allowed to comment as a newbie!). I saw something similar with BasicAer and posted a bug report in the Aer provider. It seems that BasicAer might be part of Terra instead, so maybe I posted in the wrong place. In my case, I get the expected behavior with Aer, but not with BasicAer. https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aer/issues/70

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for pointing this out. This is [a bug](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/1838) that occurs when only a subset of the qubits are measured.

It's being fixed. Until then, workarounds are:

- Use `Aer` instead of `BasicAer` (always the best thing to do when possible).
- Use `LegacySimulators` instead of `BasicAer` (this will give a deprecation warning).
- Install Qiskit from the master branch, where the issue has been fixed (here be dragons!).